# Where is my /dev/dm-2 2 GB swap partition?

Tags: partitioning, swap, lvm

On a brand new Ubuntu 22.04.2 installation, `swapon --show` shows I have a 2 GB swap partition:

```bash
$ swapon --show
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/dm-2 partition 1.9G   0B   -2
```

Neither `df -h`, nor the gparted GUI, however, shows this partition anywhere. Where is it?

Update:

Note that I have a LUKS-encrypted install.

It may be in there. `lsblk` shows something in my `nme0n1` disk:

```
nvme0n1               259:6    0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1           259:7    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2           259:8    0   1.7G  0 part  /boot
└─nvme0n1p3           259:9    0   1.8T  0 part  
  └─nvme0n1p3_crypt   253:0    0   1.8T  0 crypt 
    ├─vgubuntu-root   253:1    0   1.8T  0 lvm   /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell
    │                                            /
    └─vgubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   1.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
```

Here's what I see in gparted:

[image]

Gnome Disks doesn't show it either. Here's a snippet from Disks:

[image]

Update: double-clicking in gparted doesn't graphically show the two logical volumes, unfortunately, but it *does* *list* them under the "Logical Volumes" section at least! Here I see "root" and "swap_1" logical volumes after double-clicking the LUKS-encrypted partition in gparted:

[image]

Double-clicking in Gnome Disks has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your swap partition is a LVM partition under `nvme0n1p3` which is an encrypted partition that also contains your root file system.

Swap partitions don't have a usable file system like ext4 so tools like `df` won't show your swap partition.

I don't know why it's not showing in gparted. Is your view showing the divisions underneath `nvme0n1p3`?

Comment: `Is your view showing the divisions underneath nvme0n1p3?` No. See my gparted screenshot I just added to the question.

Comment: Can you double click on the partition for more information? This is a tad difficult to reproduce without having the same set up. But you can see that your `/` partition is also not enumerated, so it's apparent that it doesn't mean it's missing.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of the double-clicking in gparted.

Comment: Under "logical volumes", it lists `root` and `swap_1`. `swapon` also shows it's set up correctly, so you're good 

Answer (score 0):

I figured out some more info. which adds additional insight.

> Where is my /dev/dm-2 2 GB swap partition?

It's in my LUKS-encrypted partition. Although **gparted** and **Gnome Dis**ks both can*not* show the LVM (Logical Volume Manager) volumes within LUKS partitions, **blivet-gui**, a 3rd partition manager program, *can*.

### Use *blivet-gui*, instead of *gparted* or *Gnome Disks*, to see what is inside of LUKS-encrypted LVM volumes/partitions

Here's what it shows me:

As you can see, my `nvme0n1` disk has 3 partitions, with the latter being a 1.82 TiB `lvm` volume it calls `vgubuntu`:

[image]

If I double-click on it, blivet-gui shows it contains two subvolumes, which it calls type `lvmlv`. One of my logical volumes is my `vgubuntu-root` 1.82 TiB root filesystem, and the other is my `vgubuntu-swap_1` 1.91 GiB swap partition, which is apparently `swapon --show` is showing as my `/dev/dm-2` partition here:

```bash
$ swapon --show
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/dm-2 partition 1.9G   0B   -2
```

So, although my answer isn't complete either, it at least adds a little more insight. Use the **blivet-gui** partition editor to see what is inside LUKS-encrypted LVM volumes.

### To install `blivet-gui`

From my answer here: [Unix & Linux: How to edit/resize an LVM partition graphically (with a GUI)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728750/114401):

See blivet-gui's own installation instructions: https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:vtrefny&package=blivet-gui

Namely, for Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04:

```bash
# For Ubuntu 22.04
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/vtrefny/xUbuntu_22.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:vtrefny.list
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:vtrefny/xUbuntu_22.04/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_vtrefny.gpg > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install blivet-gui

# For Ubuntu 20.04
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/vtrefny/xUbuntu_20.04/ /' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:vtrefny.list
curl -fsSL https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:vtrefny/xUbuntu_20.04/Release.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/home_vtrefny.gpg > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt install blivet-gui

# etc.
```